# How to find c++ include file names when Microsoft documentation only includes C# examples

Tags: c++, .net, documentation, c++builder-10.3-rio

When MSDN only contains C# examples, and I am trying to code C++, how can I find the names of the required include files?  For example, I want to write some C++ code that uses the [`TextPointer` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.documents.textpointer?view=netframework-3.5), how do I find the `#include` statements that are required?

Comment: The `TextPointer` class is in the `System.Windows.Documents` namespace. If you try to use that namespace what hints does IntelliSense give you? And IIRC the .net header files often follows the same pattern as the namespaces, so if you try to start writing `#include <System/Windows/Documents/` what help does IntelliSense give you for that?

Comment: please clarify - are you trying to code with unmanaged C++ or with managed C++/cli?

Comment: I am actually using the current version of C++ Builder.  IntelliSense gives a constant set of modules (a few with *.h at the end, most with no file extension) which doesn't change depending on what has already been typed) - so IntelliSense is no help.  I did try just the namespace, but that gave a compile error that the file wasn't found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TextPointer` is a .NET class. C++Builder does not support .NET development, which is why its compiler  can't find any .NET related C++ header files - they don't exist in C++Builder's runtime libraries.

The only way you can use .NET classes in C++Builder projects is if either:

- the .NET classes are COM compatible (ie, have the [`[ComVisible(true)]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.comvisibleattribute?view=netframework-4.8) attribute), then C++Builder code can create instances of the appropriate COM objects.
- you wrap your .NET code in a DLL written in Visual Studio, and have it export a C compatible interface so C++Builder code can then use it.
- you use a 3rd party framework, like [CrossTalk](https://www.atozed.com/crosstalk/) or [Hydra](https://hydra.remobjects.com/hydra/), that allows C++Builder code to host the .NET runtime and use .NET assemblies and types as-is.